# Babel configuration file issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I have an issue with babel and Webpack. I shared configurations. I am getting  below error while i am running webpack build command. However i already added @babel/preset-react in .babelrc (also tried babel.config.json) files. I need some suggestion for solve this error.

[image]

```
{
  "name": "@mahiraltinkaya/react-image-upload",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/mahiraltinkaya/react-file-upload.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "next",
    "react-image",
    "image-drag-n-drop"
  ],
  "author": "Mahir Altinkaya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mahiraltinkaya/react-file-upload/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mahiraltinkaya/react-file-upload#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0"
  }
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

webpack.config.json

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "css-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: "react",
  },
};
```

Comment: `webpack.config.json`? I don't see JSON in your webpack config example.

Comment: Sorry . webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your file `babel.config.json` is not parsed. webpack is not reading it. convert it to

```
 .babelrc
```

or convert it to `babel.config.js` and have this

```
module.exports={"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}
```

Comment: Actually,  I tried both babel integration versions.  I can build with .babelrc but if I wants to use the package in my project gives me the same error.

Comment: i tested your config in one of my projects all 3 babel file types worked. do you have a github repo or can you create a reproducible code example?